# Something is blocking my thread - Blazor wasm

Tags: blazor-client-side, asp.net-blazor, matblazor

Using MatBlazor I'm trying to upload files. However, something is blocking the thread and the entire application get's blocked. I can't figure out why. It seems like the thread is blocked until the file has been loaded into the memory. 
Is it my code or is it the MatFileUploadEntry that is blocking the thread?

Does someone have any idea?

Call:

```
<MatFileUpload OnChange="@FileUpload"></MatFileUpload>
```

Response:

```
 private async Task FileUpload(IMatFileUploadEntry[] files)
    {

        var f = files.FirstOrDefault();

        if (f.Name.IsValidFileFormat())
        {

            var file = await GetFileModel(f);

            if (f.Name.IsImage())
                Model.Image = file;
            else
                Model.Document = file;


        }
    }
    private async Task<FileModel> GetFileModel(IMatFileUploadEntry f)
    {
        var sw = new Stopwatch();

        sw.Start();
        using var ms = new MemoryStream();
        await f.WriteToStreamAsync(ms);
        sw.Stop();

        var base64String = Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray());
        return new FileModel
        {
            FileName = f.Name,
            FileContentBase64 = base64String
        };
    }
```

Comment: How do you call this?  This code looks Ok but the picture is  incomplete.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I call it from the UI, like this:  <MatFileUpload OnChange="@FileUpload"></MatFileUpload>. I have tried different kind of calls but the behaviour remains the same

Comment: How big are those files?   That ToArray and ToBase64 will occupy your single thread for a bit. For the rest it seems indeed up to the MatBlazor implementation.

Comment: @HenkHolterman - A .doc file around 3 mb takes around 3 s to upload. Most of the time goes to 'file.WriteToStreamAsync(ms)'.  'Convert.ToBase64String(ms.ToArray())' takes around 200 millisec for the same size.